# How do I unlock all the secret characters?

Tags: you-must-build-a-boat

How do I unlock all the secret characters in You Must Build A Boat?

Answer (score 9):

- **Catapult** - Unlocked in Woodward's library after unlocking enough monsters.
- **Ninja** - Hides in the scenery next to your boat in the Pagoda map.
- **Wraith** - Kill a wraith in the Vault map with a *Fireball* spell.
- **Black Dragon** - Watch the paintings in the Gallery map, and tap the one that's a painting of a Black Dragon.
- **Geltower** - Eat food while fighting a Geltower inside the Mage map (the big fluffy cube)
- **Robber** - Tap your character repeatedly, making him hop at least 5 times just after you hop out of bed.
- **Skeleton King** - Sell enough items to Saundi's Broking, at least 50+. I'm guessing it's "every type of item" but I haven't been able to corroborate that.